# Cosets of subgroup of linear maps from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

$G=\{\alpha_{ab}|a,b\in \mathbb{R}\ ,a \neq {0}$} where $\alpha_{ab}$ is the mapping from $\mathbb{R} to \mathbb{R} defined as \alpha_{ab}:x\to ax+b $ 
$H=\{\alpha_{ab} \in G|a \in \mathbb{Q}\ ,a \neq {0} $} 
I can show $G$ is a group and $H$ is its subgroup but not able to find the cosets of $H$.

Please help me .

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You need $a \ne 0$.

Comment: Correct I had done Correction accordingly Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should verify that $H$ is not only a subgroup, but a normal subgroup, otherwise you can't talk about cosets (as opposed to left/right cosets). You can check that $H$ is normal by showing that $gh\in H$ if and only if $hg\in H$. The cosets are the equivalence classes under the relation $g~h$ if and only if $g^{-1}h\in H$. For any $g\in G$, you need to determine the equivalence class of maps $h\in G$ satisfying $g^{-1}h\in H$. It'll be helpful for you to explictly write what the inverse of the map $\alpha_{ab}$ is.